# NetLogo speed hacks?

Tags: optimization, netlogo

I am running my NetLogo model through R (using `RNetLogo` library) and output NetLogo's data to R to perform analysis.
In this process, I run my model thousands iterating over variables. Are there any other possible `speed hacks` in NetLogo apart from `faster speed` and `disabling view updates`?
Note:I don't prefer to disable NetLogo  GUI through R.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The profiler extension is useful for identifying which parts of your code are taking the most time. http://ccl.northwestern.edu/netlogo/docs/profiler.html

Once you've identified those parts, how to speed them up depends on the details of what the code is doing.

Comment: Thanks. I would prefer some way by which I could temporarily disable GUI of Netlogo from R and bring it back when desired. Right now it seems not possible to achieve so.

Comment: When you turn off view updates, you're getting very nearly the entire speed benefit of running entirely headless. If you measured it it would be within a few percent, I believe.

Answer (score 1):

Do you really need to integrate NetLogo and R? In other words, are you using R functions within Netlogo or vice-versa? In this case you may try to use the NetLogo-R-Extension (http://r-ext.sourceforge.net/) and check if this work faster.

If you don't need any R function, it is probably faster to separate the two platforms: first run NetLogo through the behavior space, then analyse the resulting data in R.

Comment: It just makes the task less time consuming. How much of a speed difference are we talking abt here?